# Getting events - but only tree changes

Tags: box-api

We are using Box api events endpoint to track events in users account.

We are looking for a way to get **only** events related to adding or modification of folders and files. The problem is the following:

If we set **stream_type=changes** then we don't receive COLLAB_ADD_COLLABORATOR event so we cannot detect when a new folder appears in user's account.

If we set **stream_type=all** then we get all events and majority of them are really not needed for our use case.

Basically, we need stream_type which will return all events which result in filesystem changes in user's account (basically stream_type=changes including new files and folders created via share).

Is this maybe a bug in  **stream_type=changes**?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug.  I will check on this at Box.